# Create a text file in unix server using ITRS Geneos Console

Tags: unix, geneos

I am trying to create a file in Unix server(netprobes run in this server) using ITRS Geneos active console. When I assign some alert to me or snooze any alert, a file must be created in unix server with the username who performed the action on active console.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is Option to see who all have snoozed the cells, etc.. in the Administrator entity, also if an email is set for your id in user -> info section. You shall also get any email when something is assigned to your id.

Other Option is to use OpenAccess API.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other methods other than the API.

## 1.The Gateway logs

Both Actions follow the same format. This shows you the command (Action), who did it, and where it was applied to.

### Snooze

```
<Mon Jan 29 08:16:09>  INFO: CommandManager Executing command [/SNOOZE:manualAllMe] with id [46] for request id [1]
<Mon Jan 29 08:16:09>  INFO: CommandManager Executing command '/SNOOZE:manualAllMe' on DataItem '/geneos/gateway[(@name="MyGateway")]/directory/probe[(@name="Gateway")]/managedEntity[(@name="Dataviews")]/sampler[(@name="Dataviews")][(@type="")]/dataview[(@name="Summary")]/rows/row[(@name="Row")]/cell[(@column="Col")]', issued by user 'ActiveConsole1' on '11.11.11.11'
```

### User Assignment

```
<Mon Jan 29 08:17:07>  INFO: CommandManager Executing command [/USERASSIGNMENT:assignToMe] with id [47] for request id [1]
<Mon Jan 29 08:17:07>  INFO: CommandManager Executing command '/USERASSIGNMENT:assignToMe' on DataItem '/geneos/gateway[(@name="My Gateway")]/directory/probe[(@name="Gateway")]/managedEntity[(@name="Dataviews")]/sampler[(@name="Dataviews")][(@type="")]/dataview[(@name="Summary")]/rows/row[(@name="row")]/cell[(@column="col")]', issued by user 'ActiveConsole1' on '11.11.11.11'
```

You can parse this according to your needs for the file on the server.

## 2.Parsing Dataviews

Gateway-snoozeData and Gateway-userAssignmentData plug-in provide a comprehensive view (which can be in turn parsed).

Either extract the data via webslinger and wget or via the ORB pages (by going to http://your_gateway_host:your_port/ORB)